How to specify height for merged rows in grid?
I have a grid layout defined using CSS Grid, and I want to achieve a specific layout with designated heights for certain areas. The desired grid layout looks like this:
A B C
A D E
F G E


I want the height of the area A to be 96px and the height of the area E to be 48px. All other areas should adjust their height automatically (auto).
Here's the CSS and HTML I am currently using:


.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 96px 1fr 48px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "a d e"
    "f g e";
  gap: 5px;
}

.table > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  height: 96px;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
  height: 48px;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.g {
  grid-area: g;
}
<div class="table">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <div class="g">g</div>
</div>



When I set the height for the A and E areas, the layout becomes misaligned. It seems that setting the height directly on a grid cell causes the entire layout to behave unexpectedly.
How can I set the height for specific grid areas (A and E) while keeping the layout intact and allowing other areas to adjust their height automatically?

What do you mean by "behaves unexpectedly"? It seems to be working perfectly fine on my screen. The extra height needed to fit area A within the two top rows is split evenly between the two top rows, which ends up making the second row tall enough that barely anything of area E ends up in the third row. As I would expect.

Why doesn't area E align to row 3? That's what I want



    .table {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 96px 1fr 48px;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
      gap: 5px;
    }
    <div class="table">
      <div class="">
        <div class="a">a</div>
        <div class="b">b</div>
        <div class="c">c</div>
      </div>

      <div class="">
        <div class="a">A</div>
        <div class="d">D</div>
        <div class="e">E</div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="f">F</div>
        <div class="g">G</div>
        <div class="e">E</div>
      </div>
    </div>




might it helps with your idea


Also you need to set grid-template-rows: auto calc(24px - var(--gap)) 24px; then the height of .e will be 48px:


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  --gap: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 96px 1fr 48px;
  grid-template-rows: auto calc(24px - var(--gap)) 24px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "a d e"
    "f g e";
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.table > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
  height: 96px;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.g {
  grid-area: g;
}
<div class="table">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
  <div class="e">e</div>
  <div class="f">f</div>
  <div class="g">g</div>
</div>



P.S. I recommend always starting your css code with
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}


I hope area E can align to row 3. Just added a diagram to show the layout I want.

Is it possible to be flexible that not set fixed values for the height of rows 2 and 3?

Row1 + Row2 + gap = 96px, Row2 +Row3 + gap = 48px. Apart from these conditions, other heights can adjust automatically based on its content.
